Evaulating conditional pdf efficiently given marginal pdfs
Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be two random variables with joint distribution $p(\mathbf{A},\mathbf{B})$. The joint prior is defined in relation to a data model, given by
$$\mathbf{y} = f(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{A}, \mathbf{w}), \quad \mathbb{E}\left[ \mathbf{w} \mathbf{w}^T \right] = \mathbf{B}$$
For nice distributions and nice functions $f(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{A}, \mathbf{w})$, the priors can be represented in closed-form. Consider the following example,

Let the function be linear, i.e. $f(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{A},\mathbf{w}) = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{w}$, and $\mathbf{B}$ belongs to an exponential family of distributions like $\mathbf{B} \sim \mathcal{IW}$, inverse-Wishart for the noise covariance. Let each row of $\mathbf{A}$ be Gaussian, i.e. $\mathbf{A}_{i, :} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{C})$ with known covariance $\mathbf{C}$. Then we have $\mathbf{A} \big \vert \mathbf{B} \sim \mathcal{MN}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{B}, \mathbf{C})$, a matrix-normal distribution with row covariace $\mathbf{B}$ and column covariance $\mathbf{C}$. The joint prior $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \sim \mathcal{MNIW}$ is then a matrix-normal inverse-Wishart distribution. For this case, prior conditional $p(\mathbf{A} \big \vert \mathbf{B})$ has a closed form and can easily be calculated.

Questions: How can I calculate the prior conditional $p(\mathbf{A} \big \vert \mathbf{B})$ or the joint prior distribution $p(\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B})$ if $\mathbf{A}$ is not such a nice distribution or function $f$ is not linear or both? While I would like to have a general answer, in my particular case, considering the example given above,

While the different rows of $\mathbf{A}$ are still related by covariance $\mathbf{B}$, each individual row, $\mathbf{A}_{i, :}$, is no longer multivariate Gaussian but comes from a complicated distribution $\pi$, the form of which I know. I do not know how I can go about calculating the joint prior or prior conditional given $p(\mathbf{B})$ and distribution $\pi$ are known.

The thing that comes to my mind is based on Monte-Carlo integration but I do not know how to do it. Is this even the correct way to approach it? If so, can you point to the literature necessary for me to be able to do so? Please correct me if there is something wrong in this reasoning or provide nuances/details wherever necessary.
Edit 1: Thanks to @WilliamM. in the comments for pointing out that my question didn't make any sense. I have made some major changes to account for the confusion!

You seem to be confused, if $A$ and $B$ are sampled independently from one another, then one cannot get $p(A \mid B)$ unless some mathematical model underlying $A$ and $B$ is presumed to hold. If you sample the pairs $(A,B)$ then, for a given value $B = b,$ you can definitely find what $p(A \mid b)$ is.

@WilliamM. Thanks you for the comment. I have made changes to remove the confusion. I didn't realize that my question was just wrong! Please let me know if you still find it unclear and I will do my best to clarify/make it right!
